# How can I receive GIF's from the keyboard in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, mime-types

I am trying to make a chat in jetpack compose, and I want to be able to use the standard gif keyboard on my samsung to send a gif.

When I click a GIF on a normal TextField, I am currently getting a message "Can't enter this content here"

I found something called **Commit Content API** which should make it possible to add a GIF in a old EditText so I am trying that inside an AndroidView, Now I dont get the error message anymore, But I also don't have a clue where the GIF is and how it is represented.

```
AndroidView(factory = {
    val editText = @SuppressLint("AppCompatCustomView")
    object : EditText(it) {

        override fun setOnReceiveContentListener(
            mimeTypes: Array<out String>?,
            listener: OnReceiveContentListener?
        ) {
            super.setOnReceiveContentListener(mimeTypes, listener)
        }


        override fun onCreateInputConnection(editorInfo: EditorInfo): InputConnection {
            val ic: InputConnection = super.onCreateInputConnection(editorInfo)
            EditorInfoCompat.setContentMimeTypes(editorInfo, arrayOf("image/gif"))

            val callback =
                InputConnectionCompat.OnCommitContentListener { inputContentInfo, _, _ ->
                    try {
                        inputContentInfo.requestPermission()
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        return@OnCommitContentListener false
                    }
                    true  // return true if succeeded
                }
            return InputConnectionCompat.createWrapper(ic, editorInfo, callback)
        }
    }
    editText
}) {}
```

Comment: Leave a +1 here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/198323023

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`callback` is called each time a GIF is selected. You can get the URI from `inputContentInfo`:

```
val callback =
    InputConnectionCompat.OnCommitContentListener { inputContentInfo, _, _ ->
        try {
            inputContentInfo.requestPermission()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            return@OnCommitContentListener false
        }
        gifUri = inputContentInfo.contentUri
        true  // return true if succeeded
    }
```

Perfectly, you should copy the file from this URI into your own storage and call `inputContentInfo.releasePermission()`, because `contentUri` will be freed at some point. More info can be found in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/image-keyboard).

You can display the content of this URI using Coil as showed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69092274/3585796). Note that you need to add the dependency `io.coil-kt:coil-gif:$coil_version`

A full working example:

```
var gifUri by remember { mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null) }
val context = LocalContext.current
Image(
    rememberImagePainter(
        gifUri,
        imageLoader = remember {
            ImageLoader(context).newBuilder()
                .componentRegistry {
                    if (SDK_INT >= 28) {
                        add(ImageDecoderDecoder(context))
                    } else {
                        add(GifDecoder())
                    }
                }.build()
        }
    ),
    contentDescription = null,
    modifier = Modifier.size(300.dp)
)

AndroidView(factory = { context ->
    val editText = @SuppressLint("AppCompatCustomView")
    object : EditText(context) {

        override fun setOnReceiveContentListener(
            mimeTypes: Array<out String>?,
            listener: OnReceiveContentListener?
        ) {
            super.setOnReceiveContentListener(mimeTypes, listener)
        }


        override fun onCreateInputConnection(editorInfo: EditorInfo): InputConnection {
            val ic: InputConnection = super.onCreateInputConnection(editorInfo)
            EditorInfoCompat.setContentMimeTypes(editorInfo, arrayOf("image/gif"))

            val callback =
                InputConnectionCompat.OnCommitContentListener { inputContentInfo, _, _ ->
                    try {
                        inputContentInfo.requestPermission()
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        return@OnCommitContentListener false
                    }
                    gifUri = inputContentInfo.contentUri
                    true  // return true if succeeded
                }
            return InputConnectionCompat.createWrapper(ic, editorInfo, callback)
        }
    }
    editText
}) {}
```

Comment: Thank you but I am getting an Error on this line `val input = inputContentInfo.contentUri.toFile().inputStream()` because `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Uri lacks 'file' scheme: content://com.samsung.android.honeyboard.provider/root/data/user/0/com.samsung.android.honeyboard/temp_content/com.samsung.android.icecone.gif/ff53e3cd-f276-4732-8232-02c47de5e1dc.gif`

Comment: @mama I mean using URI directly, see updated answer. Not sure exactly how to copy it to local files.

Comment: @mama this means that you are using a pre-release coil version, the API has been changed

Comment: Is there any way to do it with an OutlinedTextField?

Comment: @JacobFerrero no, it’s not yet supported, otherwise [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/198323023) would’ve been marked as complete

Comment: A supposedly workaround: https://gist.github.com/joshuamking/3234f945f2bf9fd0caf093488c90c1df. I haven't tried myself.